# How to bulk update stock for not updated products

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to be able change Stock levels to "Out of stock" or stock quanity to 0 to products that hasn't been updated.

So far i made 2 separate codes to update stock and to delete not-updated products, but i need to combine them

```
DELETE FROM     `wp_posts` WHERE     `post_modified` < "2019-05-14"

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = 'outofstock' WHERE meta_value = 'instock' AND meta_key = '_stock_status'
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're deleting data from the database

Comment: Thats my point i dont want to delete but to puto out of stock, basically first lite should be like select , and then do second line.

Comment: Im trying to use IN, but no luck.

UPDATE 
    `wp_postmeta` 
SET 
    `meta_value` = 'outofstock'
WHERE 
    meta_value = 'instock' AND meta_key = '_stock_status' 
    IN (
                SELECT 
                    `ID` 
                FROM 
                    `wp_posts` 
                WHERE 
                    `post_type` = 'product' 
                    AND `post_status` = 'publish' 
                    AND `post_modified` < "2019-05-14"
            )

Comment: Don't DELETE ANYTHING. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: finally i figured it out in case someone needs it:

Comment: UPDATE 
    `wp_postmeta` 
SET 
    `meta_value` = 'outofstock'
WHERE 
    meta_value = 'instock' AND meta_key = '_stock_status' 
   AND `post_id` IN (
                SELECT 
                    `ID` 
                FROM 
                    `wp_posts` 
                WHERE 
                    `post_type` = 'product' 
                    AND `post_status` = 'publish' 
                    AND `post_modified` < "2019-05-14"
            )

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, your query (incorrectly posted as a comment) can be rewritten as follows:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta x
  JOIN wp_posts y
    ON y.id = x.post_id
   SET x.meta_value = 'outofstock' 
 WHERE x.meta_value = 'instock' 
   AND x.meta_key = '_stock_status'
   AND y.post_type = 'product' 
   AND y.post_status = 'publish' 
   AND y.post_modified < "2019-05-14"
```